# Trouble with an Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array in local storage

```
[["Beverages","55","114.63"],["Catering","2","32"],["Bowl","107","785.43"],["Frozen Yogurt","3","14.97"],["Premium Toppings","328","496.08"],["Salad","62","493.98"],["Soup","25","96.35"],["Wrap","54","389.36"],["Retail","10","18.57"],["Juices","16","95.84"],["Smoothies","12","71.88"]]
```

And this code to access it and create a new array for high charts

```
getDeptDetailPie: function() {
    var data = new Array();
    var tempData = new Array();
    var currentData;
    currentData = JSON.parse(storage.readValue('currentDeptDetails'));

    for(var i = 0;i<=currentData.length;i++) {
        console.log(currentData[i][0]);
        if(currentData[i]) {
        tempData['name']=currentData[i][0];
        tempData['y']=currentData[i][2];
        data.push(tempData);
        tempData=[];
    }
    }
```

I am getting the uncaught type error on  line 9 which is the console.log function. but the console is logging the right data but none of it is getting placed into my tempData array.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Change to `i < currentData.length`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Off by one error

```
i<=currentData.length
```

needs to be

```
i<currentData.length
```

And `tempData` should be an object and not an array.

```
for(var i = 0;i<currentData.length;i++) {
    var tempData = {}; 
    tempData['name']=currentData[i][0];
    tempData['y']=currentData[i][2];
    data.push(tempData);
}
```

or just

```
for(var i = 0;i<currentData.length;i++) {
    data.push({ name : currentData[i][0], y : currentData[i][2]});
}
```

Or you could use forEach or map and get rid of the for loop

```
var data = currentData.map(function(val){ return { name : val[0], y : val[2]}});
```